# carriage returns in strings adding spaces how to compare

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am having some issues handling strings with carriage returns in them. (I need to keep the carriage returns. And would like to not have to code for them uniquely.) This string has 2 carriage returns...

```
Press the Switch

Drying
```

And when I view it in SQL editor of Visual Studio it appears like....

```
Press the SwitchDrying
```

Which isn't technically an issue. I can copy and paste the contents into Excel or elsewhere and it is correctly formatted.

The issue comes when I try to compare the string to another variable, even if it has the same value.

I query a set of records from my Sql 2008 R2 DB table and then compare them to an external datasoruce.

So as I loop through the records of the SQL result set....

```
For Each row As DataRow In myTable.Rows

    Dim stringVal As String = row(columnName).ToString()

    ' Eventually added this to see that the row was adding 2 spaces after the carriage return
    Dim cstringVal() As Char = stringVal.ToCharArray
    Dim csearchValue() As Char = searchValue.ToCharArray

    ' Originally tried
    If row(columnName) = searchValue And row(columnName2) = searchValue2 Then
        return True
    End If

    ' Tried this
    If stringVal = searchValue And row(columnName2) = searchValue2 Then
        Return True
    End If

    ' And this
    If String.Compare(stringVal, searchValue, False) = 0 And row(columnName2) = searchValue2 Then
        Return True
    End If
 Next
 Return False
```

After adding the char array, noticed that somehow there were 2 spaces being added after the first carriage return. Or maybe it is one space after each of them, as the CRs are not identifed in the char array.

I do not have any code that splits this string and it is only strings that have carriage returns that cause this.  The only other difference is that one string is an OLE DataAdapter and the other is a SQL DataAdapter.

What gives? any ideas?

**UPDATE**: It appears that the SQL DataAdapater is not correctly representing the carraige returns in the dataset that is returned from my query. When I view the table contents in VS SQL Editor, the string can correctly be copy and pasted from the table into any other app. I will be walking the code shortly looking the comparison of the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [new line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) is likely a combination of two bytes for CR and LF (or 0D 0A in hex, escaped as '\r\n' in C#, etc).  If your string comes from a Linux system, it likely uses a single byte LF.

String comparisons would be expected to fail if they don't account for the embedded new line characters.  If you would like to ignore newlines for purposes of the string comparison, you will have to do something like a [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to remove newline characters.  Of course you can always keep a copy of your original string that includes the newline characters.

I hope this is relevant to the problem you are seeing?

Comment: The strings are coming from another Access DB. No Linux. Thanks for the reply, I appreciate any input on this matter.

Comment: @marc11h when you say "the row was adding 2 spaces after the carriage return", are you sure those are really spaces? Sometimes nonprintable characters such as 0x0A or 0x0D get rendered as spaces (or as question marks, or as "boxes", etc). If one string has them, and the other doesn't, the two strings won't match, right?

Comment: Well they are additional character spaces in the array. I am guesing that if there was only a 0xOD that Windows appended a 0xOd 0xOa to the string giving the additional 2 spaces. I need to run some more tests tomorrow. I have identifed that there may have been a Lotus Nnotes system and perhaps Unix in the mix of managing the strings.